# How do I define an HTML anchor to jump to specific location within a page?

Tags: html, anchor

I see thousands of tutorials teaching you a very simple thing, how to use `#section` to jump to a specific section within your page. However, nobody unveils the secret of coding the target anchor. Can you do that?

Comment: "Nobody tell you how to code you page to specify the anchor" Have you tried Googling "html anchor" I see the third result says "Add Anchor Tags To Jump To Specific Location On A Page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anchor can be a `<div>`, `<table>` etc. So what you need o do is give it an `id`:

```
 <td id="tips">
```

So then, to link to it, you do the following:

```
http://a.com/a.html#tips
```

That's all.